# How to repeat values of a vector based on its own value in r

Tags: r

I want to create a vector1 that consist of the repetition of each value of another vector2 as many times as the value itself of each element of vector2

```
V2 <- c(1,3,2)
```

V1 should be:

```
c(1,3,3,3,2,2)
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `rep` to do this

```
rep(V2, V2)
#[1] 1 3 3 3 2 2
```